# Python3 - Pipenv install mysqlclient?

Tags: python, mysql-python

Trying to install from pipenv with:

```
pipenv install mysqlclient
```

will reseult in:

> Installing mysqlclient… Collecting mysqlclient   Using cached
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6f/86/bad31f1c1bb0cc99e88ca2adb7cb5c71f7a6540c1bb001480513de76a931/mysqlclient-1.3.12.tar.gz
>       Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
>       /bin/sh: 1: mysql_config: not found
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "", line 1, in 
>         File "/tmp/pip-install-5vhtqgve/mysqlclient/setup.py", line 17, in 
>           metadata, options = get_config()
>         File "/tmp/pip-install-5vhtqgve/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 44, in get_config
>           libs = mysql_config("libs_r")
>         File "/tmp/pip-install-5vhtqgve/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 26, in mysql_config
>           raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))
>       OSError: mysql_config not found
>
> ```
> ----------------------------------------
> ```
>
> Error:  An error occurred while installing mysqlclient! Command
>   "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in
>   /tmp/pip-install-5vhtqgve/mysqlclient/
>
> This is likely caused by a bug in mysqlclient. Report this to its
>   maintainers.

I'm using a Debian and with another virtualenv it get the system package

```
python-mysqldb/testing,now 1.3.10-1 amd64
```

Pipenv won't use this one and won't install the other.
How can I solve this?
Thanks,BR

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You probably need the mysql client lib for the OS.

```
sudo apt install libmysqlclient-dev
```

Then you should be able to:

```
pipenv install mysqlclient
```

Comment: Thank you! That's it: sudo apt install default-libmysqlclient-dev/testing 1.0.4 amd64
  MySQL database development files (metapackage).

Answer (score 6):

I fixed that problem with the following command:

```
brew install mysql
```

Comment: you have to be on osx to do that

Answer (score 1):

First install python-dev

**sudo apt-get install python3-dev**

and then install mysqlclient-dev version

**sudo apt-get install python3-dev libmysqlclient-dev**

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to install the file first.
On windows I used
pip install "mysqlclient-1.3.13-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl"
and the tried:
pip install mysqlclient.
It worked well.

Answer (score -1):

if you are on Centos

Try: `yum install mariadb-devel`

this package includes the missing `mysql-config`

Comment: Hi Pepperish. OP clearly states «I'm using a **Debian** and with another virtualenv it get the system package»

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

and then:

```
sudo apt-get install libmariadbclient-dev
```